# how to solve a VBA Runtime error 9 “subscript out of range.”

Tags: excel, vba

I m trying to copy columns from a sheet to another after filtering it (Autofilter). Input is a workbook (with Quelldatei) than creating 2 other sheets "FSS" and "GMS_PC.A157".

```
Dim Pfad1 As String
Dim Bezeichnung As Variant
Umsatzdatenbank = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Pfad1 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Umsatz").Cells(5, 5)
Set range4 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C3:C" & lastbez2)
Set range5 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("F3:F" & lastoffice)
lastbez2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastoffice2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim sArray4, sArray5  As Variant
sArray4 = copyToArray(range4)
sArray5 = copyToArray(range5)

Workbooks.Open Pfad1
ActiveSheet.Name = "Quelldatei"
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "GMS_PC.A157"

With Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157")
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("K1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=sArray4, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=sArray5, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157").Range("$A$1:$AA$" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'error line'
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Apologies, I see where you have commented on the error line. What is the value of `LastRow` when the script reaches this line? Are you only pasting values? If so you could simplify by using `Range.Value = Range.Value` instead of paste

Comment: Are you sure that sheet `"GMS_PC.A157"` exists? The error message suggests that it is something like `Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157")` which is failing.

Comment: This code cannot run to the line that you marked as the error line. It will fail much earlier, at least at the second `ActiveSheet.Name = "GMS_PC.A157"` where you are trying to have two sheets named "GMS_PC.A157" in the same workbook. Your `With Worksheets("GMS_PC.A157")` also has no effect because nowhere you are using the `.` syntax.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy not only values.

Comment: @JohnColeman i created this sheet "GMS_PC.A157"  (copying it from the sheet which already in that  workbook)

Comment: @GSerg sorry my mistake ! the first ActiveSheet.Name is actually ActiveSheet.Name ="Quelldatei"